# Missing Method in Mongo Legacy Java Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongo-driver-legacy

Previously we were using mongo-java-driver 3.10.2 there is a `getAddress()` method in MongoClient derived from the super class, `Mongo`. We needed to switch to **mongo-driver-legacy** 4.11.1 to be able to work with mongo 5. But now I can not see the method `getAddress()` of `MongoClient` class. How can I find the value provided by this method ? you can see below what the method does.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

plz try Get cluster description

```
client.getClusterDescription().getClusterSettings().getHosts().forEach(serverAddress -> {
                System.out.println("Server Address: " + serverAddress);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also found this but this prints all the hosts belongs to the cluster. but, if you look at the screenshot from javadoc, the method getAddress seems to be returning the master node ServerAddress.